# android gallery widget infinite scroll

Tags: android, android-widget

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement an endless gallery in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393918/how-to-implement-an-endless-gallery-in-android)

does anobody know how to make a gallery using the gallery widget instead of having edges let you cycle indefinitly.

Comment: Very interesting question. I doubt this can be done without creating your own Custom drawn widget.

Answer (score 0):

A shameless self plug, just wrote an Infinite Scrolling Gallery Tutorial:

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/

Source code can be downloaded also

You can use images on your SD card or images in your /resources/drawable directory