# how to create a circular list view or populate values in a circular view?

Tags: android, listview, layout, circular-buffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a closed (circular) ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview)

I am pretty new to android, and i would like to create a list view in a circular format.Is there anyway to do this or to create some kind of circular layout?
If the normal list view populates value in a vertical manner, i would like to have a list view that populates the values in circular format 
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3635753/718764

Comment: I think this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4107716/1265724) will help you..

Comment: this is more of a coverflow type of list.
to be more specific i wanted a top view of this.
each value taking up a sector of the circle as the values are put in.