# Creating endless full screen gallery

Tags: java, android, gallery

I'd like to create a full screen android gallery.  In this gallery I would like to be able to swipe the image off the screen like the google gallery app, but have the same image show up again.  I'd also like the next image to show up underneath the image being swiped away.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `CustomAdapter`.

Have a look at these links:

[Android Endless Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1080811/593709)

[Endless Gallery discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3393918/593709)

[CommonsWare's Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless)

And for the [Carousel of the Image here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/androcarousel.aspx) is a nice tutorial and source available