# Infinite Endless Gallery? Well,its not working for me

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I did check those posts about Infinite gallery before posting this question but it didn't work for me. The gallery remained as it was. This piece of code : `gallery.setSelection((int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2) - (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)% mImageIds.length);` doesn't affect the gallery even a bit. And whats more,instead of defining the gallery items in the `onCreate` itself just for getting the length for above `setSelection()` statement,I just wrote `7` instead of `mImageIds.length` since my gallery contains 7 items. But the `LogCat` started showing `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception`. So what choice did I have? I did what everyone would do. I removed that `7` and undid the code to the point where it was running fine. But again,the LogCat didn't come out of that error. It really is frustating. Please help.

And it will be a lot helpful if someone can help with the Endless Gallery.

Thanking you in anticipation.

LogCat :

03-17 18:46:09.681: D/android.widget.GridLayout(626): horizontal constraints: x7 - x0 > 320, x4 - x3 > 87, x5 - x4 > 0, x6 - x5 > 77, x4 - x2 < 64, x4 - x3 < 64, x2 - x1 < 64, x1 - x0 < 64 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x7 - x0 < 320, x4 - x2 < 64, x4 - x3 < 64. 
03-17 18:46:09.691: D/android.widget.GridLayout(626): vertical constraints: y1 - y0 > 21, y2 - y1 > 45, y3 - y2 > 42, y4 - y3 > 40, y5 - y4 > 10, y6 - y5 > 48, y7 - y6 > 0, y8 - y7 > 48, y9 - y8 > 0, y10 - y9 > 48, y11 - y10 > 0, y12 - y11 > 44, y12 - y10 > 48, y13 - y12 > 82, y13 - y0 < 199, y12 - y11 < 44 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y13 - y0 < 199. 
03-17 18:46:09.751: D/AndroidRuntime(626): Shutting down VM
03-17 18:46:09.751: W/dalvikvm(626): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
`03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=1073741823`
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.sanjay.frames.FramesActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(FramesActivity.java:86)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:844)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.Gallery.layout(Gallery.java:645)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.Gallery.onLayout(Gallery.java:346)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-17 18:46:09.771: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here's the code for my gallery :

```
public class FramesActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_template,
            R.drawable.th,
            R.drawable.wt,
            R.drawable.cur,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };     

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setSelection((int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2) - (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)%       mImageIds.length);

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText2.setText(""+position);
        }
    });
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_template,
            R.drawable.th,
            R.drawable.wt,
            R.drawable.cur,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Frames);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Frames_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);

        return imageView;
    }
}   
}
```

Also,I am a newbie in android development.So if you see any other mistake in the above code,don't mind pointing them out.

Comment: BTW,the gallery works fine if I just remove the `setSelection()` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the list to your adapter like so (or use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   DisplayMetrics metrics=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    Integer[] mImageIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_menu_template,
            R.drawable.th,
            R.drawable.wt,
            R.drawable.cur,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };     

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mImageIds));
    gallery.setSelection((int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2) - (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)%       mImageIds.length);

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            EditText editText2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            editText2.setText(""+position);
        }
    });
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    private Integer[] mImageIds = null;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] imageIds) {
        mContext = c;
        mImageIds = imageIds;
        TypedArray attr = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Frames);
        mGalleryItemBackground = attr.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Frames_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        attr.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (mImageIds != null) ? mImageIds.length : 0;
    }
// etc
```

if that's not helping post the error from the log and highlight the line where it happens.

Edit:

```
gallery.setSelection((int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2) - (Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)%       mImageIds.length);
```

is causing the Error.
(2000 / 2) - (2000 / 2) % 7 = 1000 - 1000 % 7 = 1000 - (1000 % 7) = 1000 - 6 = Way too big.

The result must be 0..6 if mImageIds.size == 7

What should that line do?

Comment: Nope that didn't work either.Here's the error from log : `03-17 18:34:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(587): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=1073741823
`

Comment: edit your own post, put the complete error there and the topmost line that says (YouJavaFile.java:345) is where the error occurs. Highlight that line in your post.

Comment: btw "index=1073741823" means you access mImageIds[1073741823] so your calculation with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is wrong.

Comment: can you explain how to remove the mistake? BTW,I have included the logCat details.

Comment: That line is the statement suggested by people for running the gallery in an endless fashion.I got that line from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393918/how-to-implement-in-endless-gallery-in-android-gallery-application). See the second answer.

Comment: You should use the right [Adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633370/android-circular-gallery/3635753#3635753). The trick is that the Adapter says it has `Integer.MAX_VALUE` items. Then you set the initial position to the middle of that so you have enough to scroll left and right. `getItemId()` uses modulo to calculate the real image to show.