# Gallery view with circular effect to both edges

Tags: android, gallery, horizontalscrollview

I am working on application in which gallery require as bellow image :

[image]

I searched over internet but it gives result similar to Image Gallery. But I want to create the gallery which will move in circular fashion, means it just bend the first and last member of gallery. Is it possible? or Is the **`horizontal ScrollView`** better approach to do this?

Any better approach will be appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393918/how-to-implement-an-endless-gallery-in-android)

Comment: Thanks Krishna. But I want circular effect visually not functionally. The gallery should look like bending on the edges. Any suggestion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution and it achieved using `Custom Gallery`. I used following layout file for that

`main.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gal_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/horizontallistview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />
        <!-- android:background="@drawable/gal_overlay" -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gal_overlay" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

And it uses the some images as background to `FrameLayout` and `ImageView`. You will find the complete source code of project on [GitHub](https://github.com/iamswapnilsonar/AnHorizontalListView).

Happy Coding..